# Checkbox to enable/disable other checkboxes in form

Tags: vba, ms-access, checkbox

I have a checkbox `CRShtnvsp` and if checked, I have VBA code to enable additional checkboxes. This checkbox is enabled/disabled via another checkbox `CRShtn`. That sequence works.

I want `CRShtnvsp` to enable additional checkboxes.

VBA for both `CRShtnvsp` and `CRShtn` below.

This code works:

```vb
Private Sub CRShtn_AfterUpdate()
    If CRShtn = True Then
        CRShtnvsp.Enabled = True
    Else
        CRShtnvsp.Enabled = False
    End if
End Sub
```

This code does not work:

```vb
Private Sub CRShtnvsp_AfterUpdate()
     If CRShtnvsp = True Then
          CRShtn_vaso_phen.Enabled = True
     Else
         CRShtn_vaso_phen.Enabled = False
     End if
End Sub
```

All checkboxes are set to Enabled = No in the property sheet so they are disabled until prior checkboxes or comboboxes on my form are changed using AfterUpdate() or Form_Current().

Comment: @HansUp no, expecting CRShtnvsp_AfterUpdate() to run after checking CRShtnvsp.

Comment: FYI - not your issue but you could replace the If Else with just `CRShtn_vaso_phen.Enabled = CRShtnvsp`

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks! I think someone else mentioned that to me in the past, but forgot to make the udpates. Good reminder!

Comment: @HansUp I've never tried a break point before, but will give it a shot. Will update.

Comment: @HansUp so I didn't do a break point, but I did look into it. Rather, I just commented out everything else other than the CRShtnvsp_AfterUpdate() procedure, and enabled CRShtnvsp to begin with. Nothing - the procedure isn't even working. No idea what's going on. Feels like it's going to be such an obvious solution and I'll feel like such an idiot.

Comment: I'm creating a new blank form, just to test these couple checkboxes. And using the @TimWilliams - the code now runs and the subsequent CRShtn_vaso_phen checkbox enables after checking a DIFFERENT box, that is CRShtnivf. So something is wrong with CRShtnvsp. Does it matter than I also have conditional formatting for a combobox to enable/disable when CRShtnvsp is checked and unchecked? Competing procedures?

Comment: Thank you @HansUp, I did start reading up on this and watched some videos so clarify how to step through code using the break point.

Comment: Sometimes Access seems to lose track of an event procedure.  I don't know why that happens, but if that's your situation, you can remind Access the procedure exists.  Go to the Event tab on the property sheet for your `CRShtnvsp` checkbox.  In the "After Update" property box, make sure "[Event Procedure]" is selected and then press the button labelled with 3 dots.  You should be at your existing procedure.  And I think should be enough to remind Access it exists.

Comment: @HansUp unbelievable...I hit the button with 3 dots on the event procedure, and poof. Everything works. Wow. Haha thank you so much! Change that to an answer, and I'll mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes Access seems to lose track of an event procedure. I don't know why that happens, but if that's your situation, you can remind Access the procedure exists.

Go to the *Event* tab on the property sheet for your `CRShtnvsp` checkbox. In the *"After Update"* property box, make sure *"[Event Procedure]"* is selected and then press the button labelled with 3 dots. You should be at your existing procedure. And I think that should be enough to remind Access it exists.

Answer (score 0):

CRShtnvsp is not updating as it's not being used - I would try adding the code for enabling the next button under the original button you're using and see if that works. To clarify: Add the code for enabling CRShtn_vaso_phen under the CRShtn_AfterUpdate sub.

Comment: like this?
Private Sub CRShtn_AfterUpdate()
     If CRShtn = True Then
          CRShtnvsp.Enabled = True
          CRShtn_vaso_phen.Enabled = True
     Else
         CRShtnvsp.Enabled = False
         CRShtn_vaso_phen.Enabled = False
     End if
End Sub

Comment: Yes! This should enable them both now like desired.

Comment: Update: tried that and CRShtn_vaso_phen now enables when CRShtn is checked. But that's not the sequence of events I'm hoping for. I'd like CRShtn_vaso_phen to enable only after CRShtnvsp has been checked. But  CRShtnvsp isn't enabled unless CRShtn is checked.

Comment: Add it in a separate if statement. Just below the other one.  Private Sub CRShtn_AfterUpdate()
     If CRShtn = True Then
          CRShtnvsp.Enabled = True
     Else
         CRShtnvsp.Enabled = False
     End if               

  If CRShtnvsp = True Then
          CRShtn_vaso_phen.Enabled = True
     Else
         CRShtn_vaso_phen.Enabled = False
     End if
End Sub

Comment: yeah I've tried that as well, and no luck

Comment: Hmm. Instead of using After update for CRShtnvsp use Private Sub CRShtnvsp_Change()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251571/discussion-between-elphiusmostafa-and-user17303987).